# Revoking PGP certificate for git signing

Tags: git, commit, pgp

Currently, I'm signing every commit I push with my PGP certificate and I've been doing it for the last year. I chose to use signatures for an added layer of security on my commits.
But I got to thinking; what happens if my private key gets public and I have to revoke it?
What is the strategy there? Can I update and reverify all of my commits with the new key? How does it work? I did some research and couldn't come up with a solution, so every thought an answer is appreciated!

Comment: What are the people who check your signature doing to check whether you've revoked the key you signed with?

Comment: If I would revoke my certificate, I would publish it to all of the public PGP servers.